# VW Golf TDi smoke

Tags: vw, tdi, smoke

My 44k miles 1.6 TDi after
 a 2m down hill drive from cold and stopped at lights began to smoke - burning the oil smell which lasted fo several miles.Engine has now apparently returned to normal.
Any ideas why the happened?

Comment: Where was the smoke coming from, the exhaust, or from under the bonnet (hood)?

Comment: How did it stop at the lights, was it the start/stop system active? More car details please, model, year..

Comment: Voting too close. Not enough information to answer well and OP isn't responding to comments.